# Create database script of SQL Server through query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to C# and SQL Server programming. I have a project in which I have to create a database backup automatically after every transaction. I tried SQL Server Agent jobs but unfortunately I came to know that in SQL Server 2014 Express, SQL Server Agent is not available.

Now I want to take a complete database script after every transaction in my C# application automatically. I found many ways of database script with data but all are through SQL Generate scripts Wizard. According to my need, I want an exact query that I run from C# application after every transaction and it creates a script in specific directory (replace if already exists). Thanks all.

Comment: Why not just enable snapshot isolation with `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Seems essentially equivalent to your task.

Comment: This is a dumb requirement, because Sql Server already does this natively. They're called Transaction Logs. Make sure recovery mode is set to "Full" rather than "Simple", and do frequent T-Log backups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database class or Scripter class to specify objects you need to generate script for.

[Previous Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229447/generate-database-creation-scripts)

[Previous Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140422/generating-sql-script-through-code-c-net)